# How does ((a++,b)) work?

Tags: c, function, recursion, comma-operator

In the above block of code, I am trying to understand how the line `return reverse((i++, i))` is working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
        void reverse(int i);
        int main()
        {
            reverse(1);
        }
        void reverse(int i)
        {
            if (i > 5)
                return ;
            printf("%d ", i);
    //        return reverse(i++); -- stack overflow
            return reverse((i++, i));
        }
```

I also found the below piece of code which works similarly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
        int y = 1, x = 0;
        int l = (y++, x++) ? y : x;
        printf("%d\n", l);
    }
```

I am sorry if the question is very basic one. I felt it very difficult to understand. If someone can explain, it will be helpful.

Comment: Read about [the comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator). And by the way, the expression `reverse((i++, i))` is effectively the same as `reverse(++i)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first code,

- **Case 1:**

  ```
  return reverse(i++);
  ```

  will cause stack overflow as the value of *unchanged* `i` will be used as the function argument (as the effect of post increment will be sequenced after the function call), and then `i` will be increased. So, it is basically calling the `reverse()` with unchanged argument and will cause infinite recursion.
- **Case 2:**

  OTOH,

  ```
  return reverse((i++, i));
  ```

  is the magic of [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator), which basically evaluates the left expression, discards the value and finally *returns* (i.e., the result of using the comma operator) the type and value of the evaluation of the right hand side expression. So, the *updated* value of `i` will be used as function argument.

  It is equivalent to writing

  ```
  return reverse(++i);    //pre-inrement
  ```

  where the *updated* value of `i` will be used.

---

In your second code,

```
  int l = (y++, x++) ? y : x;
```

gets evaluated in the below order

- `y++` evaluated, result ignored. `y` is incremented.
- `x++` evaluated, result considered for ternary operator. It is FALSE. (Remember, post increment). Then, `x` is increased (post-increment).
- As per the rule of the ternary operator, if the first operand (expression) is FALSE (evaluates to 0), then the third (operand) expression will get evaluated and the value will be returned.
- It returns the *incremented*  value of `x` to be stored in `l`, which is `1`.

Comment: Yes, what did I miss here?

Comment: Thank you so much @Sourav Ghosh. I had never worked on comma operator in real time. Hence found it difficult to differentiate this type of usage from an ordinary function call. Now understood properly.

Comment: @Denise You're welcome . :-)  BTW, It's "Ghosh", not _"Gosh"_. :-) (don't worry, you're not the first one to make a typo, i'm almost habituated.) and you can consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) an answer that helped you.